# How to enable a pageAction icon for a chrome extension in incognito mode?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Even after selecting the 'Allow in incognite mode' my extension which uses pageaction to render in certain urls doesn't show up in incognito mode. background.js has the following.

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  // Replace all rules ...
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    // With a new rule ...
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        // That fires when a page's URL contains a 'g' ...
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { urlContains: 'sears' },
          })
        ],
        // And shows the extension's page action.
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      }
    ]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug, so I've reported it here: [crbug.com/408326](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=408326)

As a work-around, you could enable [split incognito mode](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/incognito) by adding the following to the manifest file:

```js
"incognito": "split"
```

Unfortunately, [`chrome.runtime.onInstalled`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) is [not fired for extensions in incognito mode](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=264963), so you should avoid using this event when the extension is running in incognito mode, as follows:

```js
if (chrome.extension.inIncognitoContext) {
    doReplaceRules();
} else {
    chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(doReplaceRules);
}
function doReplaceRules() {
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    // ... add rules
  });
}
```

Comment: To which event would you add this code in the background.js file for the page action? Even though the bug you filed is fixed and in theory your workaround is not needed anymore, I noticed that if the extension has `"incognito": "split"` and the manifest also contains a `key` key (which is the case for extensions downloaded from the Web Store), then the declarativeContent is not applied to the incognito context.  In other words, your "incognito split" extension icon will be enabled if you load your extension locally and not enabled if you download it from the web store.

Comment: @Pep Extensions don't have the ability to appear in incognito windows by default. Did you enable incognito mode for your extension? I just created a crx file (using the same extension as in the first bug report, with "incognito" changed to "split"), loaded Chromium 60, installed the crx, enabled Incognito access at chrome://extensions, and opened a web page in an incognito window. The page action was shown. Then I removed the body element via the devtools, and the page action was disabled as expected (because the sample extension shows the page action if a `<body>` element exists).

Comment: I was able to refactor a couple things in my extension to be able to use `"incognito": "spanning"` instead of `"incognito": "split"`. But just to try to understand concepts with split mode, I tried to create a test extension with `"incognito": "split".  It turned out that with the test extension ([code here](https://github.com/pcondal/test-extension)), I did not get the original behavior described (i.e. load unpacked=icon enabled, web store=icon disabled).  Instead, now I do not get the page action icon enabled in incognito even when I load unpacked extension on Chrome 60.0.3112.90.

Comment: @Pep [The bug with `onInstalled` not firing in incognito mode](https://crbug.com/264963) has **not** been fixed. If you use split incognito mode, then you have to register the rules as shown in my answer.

Comment: OK thank you for clarifying. I also figured out why I had cases where the onInstalled listener was fired with `"incognito": "split" mode.  It seems that if you happen to have an incognito window open when you click on "Allow in incognito", then the page icon is enabled also for incognito.  I suppose that when Chromium developers tried to fix the bug, they happened to have an incognito window open when they clicked "Allow for incognito" and though it was also fixed for split mode.

Comment: This solution might be a work-around for `chrome.runtime.onInstalled`, but `chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged` does not work in Incognito mode. I uploaded an extension to test it and opened a new Chromium bug [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=825507).