# Chrome Extension Page Action Icon not enabled in Incognito mode but only when installed from Web Store

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension Page Action that I wish that users can run both in incognito mode and in regular mode.

The page action open new tabs with:

```
window.open(url);
```

I need that the Page Icon opens a new incognito tab if in incognito mode and a regular tab in regular mode.  Therefore, I added the following sentence in the manifest:

```
"incognito": "split",
```

In the background.js file of the extension, the following code enables the page action:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
  // Replace all rules ...
  chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    // With a new rule ...
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([
      {
        conditions: [
          new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
            pageUrl: { urlMatches: '<a_url_pattern>' },
          })
        ],
        // And shows the extension's page action.
        actions: [ new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction() ]
      }
    ]);
  });
});
```

The page action works fine (the page icon is enabled both in incognito and in non-incognito mode) if I load the extension locally.  However, after publishing the extension in the Web Store, the page icon only is enabled in non-incognito mode.

Why do I have this difference in behavior in incognito mode between loading locally or loading the published version from the web store?

BTW, before adding `"incognito", "split"` in the manifest file, the page icon was enabled both in incognito mode and in normal node in the previous published extension, so it seems that `"incognito", "split"`, which was the only line changed in the extension update has something to do with it.

**UPDATE**: After further investigation, the mismatch in behavior was not caused by the origin of the extension (i.e. load unpacked vs. web source), but depends on if there is an incognito window open when you click **Allow in incognito** in chrome://extensions.

It seems that, in split mode, if there is an incognito window open when you click **Allow in incognito**, the `onInstalled` listener will be fired both for incognito and non-incognito contexts.  However, if there is no incognito window open when you click **Allow in incognito**, then the `onInstalled` listener will be *only* fired in the non-incognito context, so the page action icon will not be enabled in incognito context.

This seems to be a Chrome bug.  A workaround for this bug is described in the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536703/how-to-enable-a-pageaction-icon-for-a-chrome-extension-in-incognito-mode/25537746).

Comment: Have you checked "Allow in incognito mode" checkbox on extension installation page?

Comment: Yes it is checked.  Actually the issue is not that the page icon does not appear, but that it is not enabled (unless run locally).  Here is the Chrome Extension in question if you are curious (extension code is not obfuscated, the page action should be enabled when you enter Google Translator Toolkit): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apsic-xbench-extension-fo/nhadbgflnognogbicnbeepnbpehlocgc

Comment: I have narrowed down a little bit.  It seems that the extension publishing on the Web Store, inserts a `key` item in the manifest.  If I copy the files downloaded from the web store and try to load them locally, the page icon is disabled in incognito mode even if it matches the pattern in `declarativeContent`. However, if I edit the manifest file to remove the `key` item, then the page icon is enabled when it matches the pattern in `declarativeContent`.  It seems like for incognito mode, `key` and `"incognito": "split"` cannot coexist in the same manifest file.

Comment: I found [this thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=258090&q=incognito%20split%20page%20action&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) that gives me an idea.  In incognito split mode, the rules installed by `chrome.runtime.onInstalled` are installed in the normal registry not in the incognito registry (because in split it is not shared).  Therefore, it seems that I have to find a way to install again the declarativeContent rules, when I know that I am in incognito mode.